# Php to Php Argument Sending In Different Path

Tags: php, linux, posting

I want to send some arguments from xxx.php to yyy.php , but yyy.php in different directory like /home/root.

Is there any way to do this in simple way ? I  will take these argument and use it with in different directory permission ?

Thanks ...
Best Regards

Comment: did you ever tried anything to accomplish this ?

Comment: I couldnt find useful info about that  and Yes I tried . I m  new in this language but the informations are not about what I wanted in sites

Comment: Your question is unclear, since you in no way describe _how_ you use those php scripts... Are you operating on command line base? Or is there a http server controlling requests to those scripts?

Comment: I m taking some values from the webserver , then I need to post this values to the serial port , but I need to be in the root directory so I created one php file which will send dats from root directry but I have a problem about How can I take this values from other xxx.php file to yyy.php file

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
file_get_contents("http://base.url/home/root/yyy.php?arg1=abcd&agr2=xyz")
```

Comment: Frankly I doubt that the path `/home/root` referred to the published document tree inside a http server. Sounds more like some absolute file system path to me. Which raises doubt on whether the OP is actually thinking of http requests at all...

Comment: is there any way to access this arguments without taking from server like  file_get_contents("/usr/share/index.php?arg1=abcd&agr2=xyz");